# How can I get sensors values with xamarin forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms, sensors

I want to get the values of sensors with Xamarin forms. I found tutorials on how do it with the Android project but not with App.cs which is the shared project in xamarin forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer I will use the device Motion Plugin :
https://components.xamarin.com/view/DeviceMotionPlugin